# How can i pass instance attribute in function argument in python

Tags: python, django

I have this function code

```
   def getList(self, cursor=self.conn_uat.cursor()):
        from pprint import pprint
        cursor.execute(...)
```

I am getting this error

`NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

The reason i am using in args is so that i dont put any dependency inside any function to make testing easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` is only available *inside* the method `getList`.  However, you are trying to access outside of the method in the function declaration line.  Hence, you get a `NameError`.

I think the easiest/cleanest solution would be to do this instead:

```
def getList(self, cursor=None):
    from pprint import pprint
    cursor = self.conn_uat.cursor() if cursor is None else cursor
    cursor.execute(...)
```

The functionality of the above code is identical to what you were trying to use.

Also, here is a reference on [conditional operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/ternary-conditional-operator-in-python) if you want it.

Answer (score 0):

The function is defined in the class declaration, so the specific instance isn't known. The arguments are created at definition, not at run

Here's another example of it:
["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)